# Dynamically Load 2 different DLL's with the same API in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have a C++ application that implements external user written "Apps" as DLLs. My plan to implement this is by loading dlls in a specific directory and starting a new thread for each DLL. Each DLL has its own "main" that is just an exported function __dllspec(dllexport).

I basically treat DLLs that use this API as a poormans executable (no virtual address space, less secure, its just a thread instead of a seperate process etc)

The main loader code basically calls the "main" function in the DLL while maintaining the list of loaded DLL handles.

Also I'd like these Apps to draw to a dedicated space provided by the main loader. I would provide this ability via a UI API provided by the loader exposed by requiring Apps to dllimport the required functionality.

My question is, is there another way to implement this app like functionality where "Apps" can be removed or added during runtime?

Comment: I don't understand the question. DLLs exist specifically so they can be loaded and unloaded at runtime. What is the actual problem you are having with that?

Comment: "*I would provide this ability via a UI API provided by the loader exposed by requiring Apps to dllimport the required functionality.*" - a DLL should not import functions from the main exe. The main exe should pass pointers to its functions to a DLL as needed. In this case, you can do that as an extra parameter to the DLL's "main" function, ie by passing it a pointer to a struct that holds function pointers.

Comment: @remy it is supported for a dll to import functions from its host, although I think it really needs to be done with GetProcAddress